Question about Android SDK extensions level
Right now I am responding to a recent permission change about READ_IMAGES, and applying this new api called PickMultipleVisualMedia to my app.
When I finished my work and testing, I found out that in Android 11 and 12, I couldn't fire new PickMultipleVisualMedia and, I discovered that in 11 and 12, I need SDK Extension level above 2. and here is my question
Does SDK extension level is fixed when the device provider ships it ? if its not how can I update the extension level of my device?
I have multiple emulator device with android 11, 12 and real device with 12. Every device of 11 has extension level 0, and 12 has extension level 1
what did I try

build.gradle setting (compileSdkExtension set to proper level refer to compileSdkVersion)

